# Remove margins on mobile phone

Tags: html, css

The website is http://www.jokerleb.com, it currently look like this on mobile

[image]

The client wants it to look like this

[image]

Basically no margins and similar alignment for the post and images, I tried to remove margins but little success.

The relevant code

```css
#DIV_1 {
    color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
    height: 265px;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(79, 79, 79);
    width: 167.406px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
    perspective-origin: 87.7969px 136.594px;
    transform-origin: 87.7969px 136.594px;
    caret-color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(79, 79, 79);
    border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
    font: normal normal normal normal 12px / 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(79, 79, 79) none 0px;
    padding: 4.09375px;
}/*#DIV_1*/

#DIV_2 {
    color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
    float: left;
    height: 91px;
    max-width: 85px;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(79, 79, 79);
    width: 85px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
    perspective-origin: 44.1719px 45.5px;
    transform-origin: 44.1719px 45.5px;
    caret-color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
    border: 0px none rgb(79, 79, 79);
    font: normal normal normal normal 12px / 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(79, 79, 79) none 0px;
    padding: 0px 3.34375px 0px 0px;
}/*#DIV_2*/

#A_3 {
    color: rgb(38, 38, 38);
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(38, 38, 38);
    column-rule-color: rgb(38, 38, 38);
    caret-color: rgb(38, 38, 38);
    border: 0px none rgb(38, 38, 38);
    font: normal normal normal normal 12px / 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(38, 38, 38) none 0px;
}/*#A_3*/

#IMG_4 {
    color: rgb(38, 38, 38);
    height: 85px;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(38, 38, 38);
    width: 85px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(38, 38, 38);
    perspective-origin: 42.5px 42.5px;
    transform-origin: 42.5px 42.5px;
    caret-color: rgb(38, 38, 38);
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(38, 38, 38);
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    font: normal normal normal normal 12px / 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(38, 38, 38) none 0px;
}/*#IMG_4*/

#DIV_5 {
    color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
    height: 265px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 76.2791%;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(79, 79, 79);
    width: 167.406px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
    perspective-origin: 83.7031px 132.5px;
    transform-origin: 83.7031px 132.5px;
    caret-color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
    border: 0px none rgb(79, 79, 79);
    font: normal normal normal normal 12px / 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(79, 79, 79) none 0px;
}/*#DIV_5*/

#DIV_5:after {
    clear: both;
    color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
    content: '"' '"';
    display: table;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(79, 79, 79);
    column-rule-color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
    caret-color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
    border: 0px none rgb(79, 79, 79);
    font: normal normal normal normal 12px / 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(79, 79, 79) none 0px;
}/*#DIV_5:after*/

#DIV_5:before {
    color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
    content: '"' '"';
    display: table;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(79, 79, 79);
    column-rule-color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
    caret-color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
    border: 0px none rgb(79, 79, 79);
    font: normal normal normal normal 12px / 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(79, 79, 79) none 0px;
}/*#DIV_5:before*/

#DIV_6 {
    bottom: -12px;
    color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
    float: right;
    height: 24px;
    right: 24px;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(79, 79, 79);
    width: 123.375px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
    perspective-origin: 61.6875px 12px;
    transform-origin: 61.6875px 12px;
    caret-color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
    border: 0px none rgb(79, 79, 79);
    font: normal normal normal normal 12px / 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(79, 79, 79) none 0px;
}/*#DIV_6*/

#SPAN_7 {
    bottom: 0px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 24px;
    left: 0px;
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    top: 0px;
    width: 81.375px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    perspective-origin: 51.6875px 12px;
    transform-origin: 51.6875px 12px;
    caret-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background: rgb(38, 38, 38) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    font: normal normal normal normal 11px / 24px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 12px;
}/*#SPAN_7*/

#SPAN_7:after {
    bottom: 10px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    content: '""';
    display: block;
    height: 4px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 99.375px;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    top: 10px;
    width: 4px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    perspective-origin: 2px 2px;
    transform-origin: 2px 2px;
    caret-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal normal normal 11px / 24px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}/*#SPAN_7:after*/

#SPAN_7:before {
    bottom: 0px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    content: '""';
    display: block;
    height: 0px;
    left: -12px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 103.375px;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    top: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    perspective-origin: 6px 12px;
    transform-origin: 6px 12px;
    caret-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-top: 12px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right: 12px solid rgb(38, 38, 38);
    border-bottom: 12px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-left: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    font: normal normal normal normal 11px / 24px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}/*#SPAN_7:before*/

#P_8 {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    float: right;
    height: 22px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    width: 81.375px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    perspective-origin: 40.6875px 15.5px;
    transform-origin: 40.6875px 15.5px;
    caret-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: normal normal normal normal 16px / normal "Open Sans", sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
    padding: 1px 0px 8px;
}/*#P_8*/

#H3_9 {
    color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
    height: 34px;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(79, 79, 79);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 167.406px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
    perspective-origin: 83.7031px 17px;
    transform-origin: 83.7031px 17px;
    caret-color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
    border: 0px none rgb(79, 79, 79);
    font: normal normal bold normal 17px / 17px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    outline: rgb(79, 79, 79) none 0px;
}/*#H3_9*/

#A_10 {
    color: rgb(38, 38, 38);
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(38, 38, 38);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    column-rule-color: rgb(38, 38, 38);
    caret-color: rgb(38, 38, 38);
    border: 0px none rgb(38, 38, 38);
    font: normal normal bold normal 17px / 17px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(38, 38, 38) none 0px;
}/*#A_10*/

#DIV_11, #DIV_19, #DIV_22 {
    clear: both;
    color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(79, 79, 79);
    width: 167.406px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
    perspective-origin: 83.7031px 0px;
    transform-origin: 83.7031px 0px;
    caret-color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
    border: 0px none rgb(79, 79, 79);
    font: normal normal normal normal 0px / 0px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(79, 79, 79) none 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}/*#DIV_11, #DIV_19, #DIV_22*/

#P_12 {
    color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    height: 58px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(175, 175, 175);
    width: 167.406px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    column-rule-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    perspective-origin: 83.7031px 33px;
    transform-origin: 83.7031px 33px;
    caret-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    border: 0px none rgb(175, 175, 175);
    font: normal normal normal normal 11px / 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    outline: rgb(175, 175, 175) none 0px;
    padding: 4px 0px;
}/*#P_12*/

#SPAN_13 {
    color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(175, 175, 175);
    word-wrap: break-word;
    column-rule-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    caret-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    border: 0px none rgb(175, 175, 175);
    font: normal normal normal normal 11px / 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(175, 175, 175) none 0px;
    padding: 0px 7px 0px 0px;
}/*#SPAN_13*/

#SPAN_13:before {
    color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    content: '""';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(175, 175, 175);
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 20px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    column-rule-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    perspective-origin: 10px 10px;
    transform-origin: 10px 10px;
    caret-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    border: 0px none rgb(175, 175, 175);
    font: normal normal normal normal 20px / 20px dashicons;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
    outline: rgb(175, 175, 175) none 0px;
}/*#SPAN_13:before*/

#A_14, #A_16, #SPAN_18 {
    color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(175, 175, 175);
    word-wrap: break-word;
    column-rule-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    caret-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    border: 0px none rgb(175, 175, 175);
    font: normal normal normal normal 11px / 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(175, 175, 175) none 0px;
}/*#A_14, #A_16, #SPAN_18*/

#SPAN_15 {
    color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(175, 175, 175);
    word-wrap: break-word;
    column-rule-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    caret-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    border: 0px none rgb(175, 175, 175);
    font: normal normal normal normal 11px / 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(175, 175, 175) none 0px;
    padding: 0px 7px 0px 5px;
}/*#SPAN_15*/

#SPAN_17 {
    color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(175, 175, 175);
    word-wrap: break-word;
    column-rule-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    caret-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    border: 0px none rgb(175, 175, 175);
    font: normal normal normal normal 11px / 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(175, 175, 175) none 0px;
    padding: 0px 7px 0px 5px;
}/*#SPAN_17*/

#SPAN_17:before {
    color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    content: '""';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(175, 175, 175);
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 20px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    column-rule-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    perspective-origin: 10px 10px;
    transform-origin: 10px 10px;
    caret-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    border: 0px none rgb(175, 175, 175);
    font: normal normal normal normal 20px / 20px dashicons;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
    outline: rgb(175, 175, 175) none 0px;
}/*#SPAN_17:before*/

#P_20 {
    color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
    height: 54px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(79, 79, 79);
    width: 167.406px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    column-rule-color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
    perspective-origin: 83.7031px 33px;
    transform-origin: 83.7031px 33px;
    caret-color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
    border: 0px none rgb(79, 79, 79);
    font: normal normal normal normal 12px / 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    outline: rgb(79, 79, 79) none 0px;
    padding: 6px 0px;
}/*#P_20*/

#P_21 {
    clear: both;
    color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    float: right;
    height: 18px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(175, 175, 175);
    width: 108.844px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    column-rule-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    perspective-origin: 54.4219px 9px;
    transform-origin: 54.4219px 9px;
    caret-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    border: 0px none rgb(175, 175, 175);
    font: normal normal normal normal 11px / 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    outline: rgb(175, 175, 175) none 0px;
}/*#P_21*/

#DIV_23 {
    clear: both;
    color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(79, 79, 79);
    width: 167.406px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
    perspective-origin: 83.7031px 0px;
    transform-origin: 83.7031px 0px;
    caret-color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
    border: 0px none rgb(79, 79, 79);
    font: normal normal normal normal 0px / 0px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(79, 79, 79) none 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}/*#DIV_23*/
```

```html
<div id="DIV_1">
 <div id="DIV_2">
   <a href="http://www.jokerleb.com/ads/honda-crv-2012-2/" title="Honda CRV 2012" id="A_3"><img width="250" height="250" src="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/584970-250x250.jpg" alt="IMG_9935" id="IMG_4" /></a>
 </div>
 <div id="DIV_5">
  <div id="DIV_6">
   <span id="SPAN_7"></span>
   <p id="P_8">
    $19,999.00
   </p>
  </div>
  <h3 id="H3_9">
   <a href="http://www.jokerleb.com/ads/honda-crv-2012-2/" id="A_10">Honda CRV 2012</a>
  </h3>
  <div id="DIV_11">
  </div>
  <p id="P_12">
    <span id="SPAN_13"><a href="http://www.jokerleb.com/ad-category/vehicles/cars/honda/" rel="tag" id="A_14">Honda</a></span> <span id="SPAN_15"><a href="http://www.jokerleb.com/author/joker-dealshotmail-com/" title="Posts by joker.deals@hotmail.com" rel="author" id="A_16">joker.deals@hotmail.com</a></span> <span id="SPAN_17"><span id="SPAN_18">July 8, 2017</span></span>
  </p>
  <div id="DIV_19">
  </div>
  <p id="P_20">
   EXL / special edition / telephone / rear camera / 2 Keys / new tyres
  </p>
  <p id="P_21">
   34 total views, 0 today
  </p>
  <div id="DIV_22">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="DIV_23">
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to copycat http://jsfiddle.net/4n4exrd7/ . [Here](https://m.propertyfinder.com.lb/search?l=&q=&c=1&t=&pf=&pt=&bf=&bt=&af=&at=&kw=)

Comment: please have a look on media queries, that should help you

Comment: Is this a minimal example that shows the problem? [mcve] Do the example images really need to be this big? Do we really need to see all that?

Comment: @Rob yes you need to see the images (i guess) because they have margin. You see, if I really what code you need to see that would mean I know what class is causing the problem, and that means I know how to fix it. What really sucks about css is that, it's not like any other programming language, a div in the header might be causing all the troubles. CSS sucks, all I can do is try my best to show the code

Comment: @Rob I used https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/snappysnippet/blfngdefapoapkcdibbdkigpeaffgcil but again css is not a programming language, it's guess the problem language so I tried my best. see omislav Svecak answer, he tells me to edit the header, the header!

Comment: @Rob ahh sorry you want me to remove the images from the post, as in the screenshot, well all phones take screenshot that big, and I wont include screenshots again

Comment: I didn't say that. I said they were too big and I resized them for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code and it seems like you have this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .header_top_res, .header_top_res, .header_main_res, .header_menu_res, .content_res, #search-bar, .footer_main_res, .footer_menu_res {
      width: 90%;
  }
}
```

Which gives you spacing on the sides and then you have this

```
.post-block-out {
    margin: 0 0 8px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Which gives you that margin bottom.
Just add another media query like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .content_res {
      width: 100%;
  }
  .post-block-out {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want this:

```
@media screen and (max-width:400px)
{
body{
margin:0px;
    }
}
```

Add this to your CSS

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.
In media queries remove margin values and give as "auto"

```
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
margin:auto;
}
```